# jQuery not removing class on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in Javascript

```
// when I click on any #type_import_block, remove class "active" from all id that contains "ver_"
$("[id*=_import_block]").mousedown(function(){
    $("[id*=ver_]").removeClass("active");
});
```

But doesn't work, the class "active" isn't removed from `#ver_`

Can someone help me?

Comment: We need a sample of your html. Your code works as-is given correct html.

Comment: alert($("[id*=ver_]")) and see if your selector works.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else.  Please supply a complete working reproduction.

Comment: Try to wrap attribute value in quotes

Comment: Are you sure your handler is working?  Are any `_import_block` elements added after this handler is bound?  Also, why are you using `mousedown` and not `click`?

Comment: Odd, seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/aAc6S/3/

Answer (score -2):

You need to put the attribute matching string inside quotes, like this:

```
$('[id*="_import_block"]')
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aAc6S/

Comment: I just removed the Quotes in your fiddle .. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/aAc6S/1/ .. Still works

Comment: @fegemo, he just wanted to say that it will work without `inside quotes` which really does!

Comment: jQuery('[attribute*="value"]') // 
    value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string. //

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/